# How to make a weighted sum layer with trainable weight and a definable number of inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make a weighted sum layer that performs a weighted sum of multiple parallel layers similar to the one posted [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/80750/how-can-i-perform-weighted-addition-of-three-layers-in-keras) except that I want to be able to define the number of inputs layers (i.e. n number of weights where n is defined as instantiation), and I want to use normalized weights. However, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multi_fidelity_training_full_link.py", line 341, in <module>
    main()
  File "multi_fidelity_training_full_link.py", line 283, in main
    linked_model.fit(x,y,batch_size = batch_size, epochs = mult_of*(1+i), verbose = 2, initial_epoch = mult_of*i)
  File "/usr/WS2/mvander/py3venv/py3venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1183, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "/usr/WS2/mvander/py3venv/py3venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/WS2/mvander/py3venv/py3venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 950, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/WS2/mvander/py3venv/py3venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3024, in __call__
    filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/WS2/mvander/py3venv/py3venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1961, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "/usr/WS2/mvander/py3venv/py3venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 596, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/usr/WS2/mvander/py3venv/py3venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 75, in quick_execute
    raise e
  File "/usr/WS2/mvander/py3venv/py3venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: linked_model/high_fidelity_model/weighted_sum/truediv:0
```

My code is this:

```
class WeightedSum(krs.layers.Layer):
    def __init__( self, n_models = 2, **kwargs):
        super( WeightedSum, self ).__init__( **kwargs)
        self.n_models = n_models
        w_init = tf.random_uniform_initializer()
        self.sum_weights = tf.Variable(initial_value = w_init(shape=(1,self.n_models)),trainable=True)
        self.sum_weights = tf.divide(self.sum_weights,tf.math.reduce_sum(self.sum_weights))

    def call(self,inputs):
        self.sum_weights = tf.divide(self.sum_weights,tf.math.reduce_sum(self.sum_weights))
        output = tf.multiply(tf.cast(self.sum_weights[0,0],inputs[0].dtype),inputs[0])
        for i in range(1,len(inputs)):
            output += tf.multiply(inputs[i],tf.cast(self.sum_weights[0,i],inputs[0].dtype))

        return output
```

How do I make this work?

Note: I have a different version of this code that looks quite different that builds and trains but produces a unicode error when trying to save. The error is almost certainly coming from my WeightedSum layer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem requires the implementation of a constraint and the use of the `add_weight` function. The constraint is required because, for some reason, `tf.divide` cannot be used in the manner demonstrated in the question.

```
class NormalizeSumWeights(krs.constraints.Constraint):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(NormalizeSumWeights,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self,w):
        return tf.math.divide(w,tf.math.reduce_sum(w))
```

with the WeightedSum class being changed to this.

```
class WeightedSum(krs.layers.Layer):
    def __init__( self, n_models = 2, **kwargs):
        super( WeightedSum, self ).__init__( **kwargs)
        self.n_models = n_models

    def build(self,input_shape):
        self.sum_weights = self.add_weight(name="sum_weights",shape=(1,self.n_models),
                                    initializer = krs.initializers.RandomUniform(0,1.0),
                                    constraint = NormalizeSumWeights(),
                                    trainable = True)

    def call(self,inputs):
        output = tf.multiply(tf.cast(self.sum_weights[0,0],inputs[0].dtype),inputs[0])
        for i in range(1,len(inputs)):
            output += tf.multiply(inputs[i],tf.cast(self.sum_weights[0,i],inputs[0].dtype))

        return output

    def get_config(self):
        data = { "n_models": self.n_models}
        return data
```